# Exactly what ports must be open for MSVSMON.exe (remote debugging) to work?

Tags: visual-studio, firewall, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm asking my network admin to open up ports on the firewall to allow remote debugging.  It says in the documentation on MSDN that it needs UDP 135.  However, the admin says that a number of non-standard 19xx ports are being used.

Exactly what ports are required for remote debugging to work?

Answer (score 6):

You need to open ports on both your computer and the remote computer. Primarily it's TCP 135 not UDP 135.

All the ports and steps are listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0d7tte4(v=vs.120).aspx

You can link your Admin to that page. If you don't have IPSec rules it basically comes down to:

Your PC:
TCP 135

Remote PC:
TCP 135, TCP 139, TCP 445, UDP 137, and UDP 138

Update: Fix the link as it was updated. Note, Remote Debugging transport changed significantly between Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012+. The above ports should work for VS2010. Follow the link to see more information on VS2012+.

Comment: Fyi... Granted this post is a few years old but "This topic is no longer available".

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2013 I just needed to open 4018 and 4019 and it works like a breeze

Comment: Nothing on the server itself?  Only these on the VS dev system?

Comment: No that port needs to be open on the machine that's hosting remote debugger

Answer (score 0):

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging?view=vs-2022

For Visual Studio 2022 the remote computer needs

TCP Incoming

- 4026 for VS 2022
- 4025 for VS 2022 and Microsoft Azure App Service. This port is only used to remote debug a 32-bit process from a 64-bit version of the remote debugger
- 4024 for Microsoft Azure App Service

TCP Outgoing

- 3702