# Visual Studio 2013 Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, iis-7.5, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a Web API that I have running in IIS on my machine.

When I go to attach to the process w3wp.exe, I get the error listed above.

Steps I have already taken:

- Manually started msvsmon.exe.  I still get the same error.
- I downloaded from Microsoft the appropriate Remote Debugger. (It appears to start msvmom.exe). I still get the same error.

I am running on Win 7 64x.  Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: Not sure if you're trying to debug & run IIS from the same machine; but if it's on a different one - are the firewall ports open? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135635/exactly-what-ports-must-be-open-for-msvsmon-exe-remote-debugging-to-work

Comment: All on the same machine.

Comment: OK.  When you click "Attach to Process" it shows my machine hostname in the Qualifier.   If I click the Find button it then showed {ip address}:{port} in the qualifier.  I am now able to attach to the w3wp.exe, however if I call the APPI from fiddlr I am not hitting my breakpoint.